# How to wait for Cancellation Token Register method within a PLINQ

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task, plinq, cancellation-token

As you can see in my code  below, the ProcessThisEmployee is called for each of the Employee. Within that method, I call Clean method of third party library when the operation is cancelled.
Let's say that Clean method takes quite a bit of time. What I would like to do is display some message in UI when Clean method for all running instances of ProcessThisEmployee method is completed.
This means that I need to wait for completion of all Clean methods. For now, I have a WaitAll for tasks but I am not sure if it will wait for all canellations to complete as well. Any ideas?

```
class ProcessEmployees
{
    private List<Employee> _Employees;
    CancellationTokenSource cs = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public ProcessEmployees()
    {
        _Employees = new List<Employee>() 
        {
            new Employee() { ID = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
            new Employee() { ID = 2, FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Saul" },
            new Employee() { ID = 3, FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Sue" },
            new Employee() { ID = 4, FirstName = "Catherina", LastName = "Desoza" },
            new Employee() { ID = 5, FirstName = "Paul", LastName = "Smith" }
        };
    }

    public void StartProcessing()
    {
        try
        {
            Task[] tasks = this._Employees.AsParallel().WithCancellation(cs.Token).Select(x => this.ProcessThisEmployee(x, cs.Token)).ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            // error handling code
        }
        // other stuff
    }

    private async Task ProcessThisEmployee(Employee x, CancellationToken token)
    {
        ThirdPartyLibrary library = new ThirdPartyLibrary();
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        using(token.Register(() => library.Clean())
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => library.SomeAPI(x) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just abandon the background work and immediately make the UI appear as if cancellation was complete? This is usually how reliable cancellation is done.

Comment: problem is this library do some expensive operations (like launching some external processes) so its really important to somehow make sure that clean-up just has finished before I provide confirmation to users that cancellation is done and they can go ahead with Re-try (or whatever they wanna do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can easily wait for all these using a `CountdownEvent`. You set it's size at the start, signal it after every `library.Clean()` and wait for it to reach 0 using `Wait()`:

```
private CountdownEvent _countdownEvent;
public void Cancel()
{
    cs.Cancel();
    _countdownEvent.Wait();
    // Update UI
}

public void StartProcessing()
{
    try
    {
        _countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(_Employees.Count);
        Task[] tasks = this._Employees.AsParallel().WithCancellation(cs.Token).Select(x => this.ProcessThisEmployee(x, cs.Token)).ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        // error handling code
    }
    // other stuff
}

private async Task ProcessThisEmployee(Employee x, CancellationToken token)
{
    ThirdPartyLibrary library = new ThirdPartyLibrary();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    using(token.Register(() => { library.Clean(); _countdownEvent.Signal(); })
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => library.SomeAPI(x) );
    }
}
```

However, you need to realize that what you're trying to do could be dangerous since you can't control when cancellation is initiated. If some of your employees are before or after the using block and you cancel the operation `library.Clean` won't be called and so you can wait for it forever.